# filter query using list of Enum type in Entityframework core

Tags: sql, postgresql, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-core, linq-to-entities

I have an issue filtering the query using a list of enum type

```
public enum Offer{
  
    None=1,
    all,
    stop
}

Class Emp{
[Column(TypeName = "jsonb")]
 public list<Offer> offer { get; set; }

 public D d { get; set }

public string FullName { get; set }

}

class D
{
   
 public string age { get; set }

 public string countryCode { get; set }

} 

public async Task<List<Emp>> ListEmp( List<Offer> offer ){

var query= catalogDb.Emp.Include(a=>a.D)

              .Where(a=>a.Name="xyz")

              .AsQueryable();


   if(offer.count>0){

     // need a query for filter offer column using multiple List<Offer> parameters

      **query=query.Where(i=>i.Offers.Contains(offer))**
     
     // can filter only one value USING CONTAINS
   }

 return await query.ToListAsync();

}
```

I need a query to filter the `offer` column with multiple parameters before using `query.ListAsync()`

`public list<Offer> offer` can accept   null value as well

**Database table name same as class name**

we store multiple values. that's why we use List type Offer field response save that column like

> [1,2] or [], [1,2,3], [2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(offer.Count>0){

   var result=query.AsEnumerable()
         .Where(y => y.Offers.Any(z => offer.Contains(z)))
          .ToList();
           return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `offer` variable is a list of `Offer` values, but the `List<T>.Contains` method expects a single `Offer` value.

Try:

```
if (offer.Count > 0)
{
    query = query.Where(i => i.Offers.Any(o => offer.Contains(o)));
}
```

Comment: I need to filter the query for all offer parameter values. Is there any way to write a query?

Comment: So something like `.Where(i => offer.All(o => i.Offers.Contains(o)))` then?

Comment: offer is a jsonb type column

Comment: @AGMohamed That information isn't mentioned anywhere in your question. If you're storing multiple values in a single column in your database, then you're going to need to load all records and filter in-memory.

Comment: @
Richard Deeming
we store multiple values. that's why we use List type Offer field
response save that column like [1,2] or [], [1,2,3], [2]  ...
do you know-how the query will be?